# CSS and height of the elements

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, less

How can I set the height of the div-s in my SPA app so that the following criteria will be met (black and red borders are just for the representation purposes):

1. Black border: everything within it must fit the size of the screen and not extend further - vertical scrolling is only possible within div4.
2. The red boxes in each view must be of the same height and aligned (like in the picture).

[image]

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `height`, all you need is a flex layout.

```css
.wrapAll{
  height: calc(100vh - 4px); 
  /* 4px due to borders */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

[class^=div]{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div1 {
  flex-basis: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.otherDivs {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.leftBar {
  flex-basis: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.body{
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.div2, .div3, .div4, .div5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.div4 {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* styling */

.wrapAll {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.leftBar {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.body {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.div1 {
  background: #719ecf;
}

.div2 {
  background: #fdf599;
}

.div3 {
  background: #fcf266;
}

.div4 {
  background: #6fee99;
}

.div5 {
  background: #234fcc;
  color: white;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapAll">
  <div class="div1">div1</div>
  <div class="otherDivs">
    <aside class="leftBar">
      <div class="div2">div2</div>
      <div class="div3">div3</div>
      <div class="div4">div4</div>
    </aside>
    <main class="body">
      <div class="div5">div5</div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>
```